# JavaScript broke?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the toprightradius, but it wont set? I've tried this in the console too, it runs with no errors and it just wont set. When setting a border, the border will be positioned as if the radius worked (have a curved edge) but the original background color will still shown behind the border.

```js
$('ul#parent-nav').children('li').last().style.borderTopRightRadius = "19px";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="tabs is-boxed">
    <ul id="parent-nav">
        <li class="is-active">
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp; {{ Auth::user()->username }}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp; Page1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> &nbsp; Page2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i> &nbsp; Page3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're using jQuery. `$("ul#parent-nav li:last-child").css("border-top-right-radius", "19px");`

Comment: This changes nothing, and even if it did, it would stop the border attribute which I mentioned before as working from working in the first place.

Comment: That works absolutely fine. If it's not working for you then, please check the console for errors and also update the question to include a sample of the non-working code.

Comment: `the original background color` - which original background color? What would help is if you included minimal code that demonstrates exactly what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the jQuery syntax and add `overflow:hidden` to the element to avoid unwanted overflow after applying the radius.

```js
$('ul#parent-nav').children('li').last().css('border-top-right-radius',"19px");
```

```css
li {
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:110px;
 height:50px;
 background:red;
 border:1px solid;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="tabs is-boxed">
  <ul id="parent-nav">
    <li class="is-active">
      <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> active</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp; Page1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> &nbsp; Page2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i> &nbsp; Page3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This changes nothing, and even if it did, it would stop the border attribute which I mentioned before as working from working in the first place.

Comment: This still shows the background color heigher than the border in my example. https://i.imgur.com/uvTZnAx.png

Comment: That means that the background colour is set on a different element to the one which you are applying the rounded border to. You need to check your CSS.

Comment: @tocicut check update, you need to add overflow:hidden also

Comment: @TemaniAfif that is unlikely to make a difference given the issue the OP describes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i guess it's an X/Y problem ... the issue is not with border-radius but with other styling and CSS ... will delete this answer if the OP doesn't more information

Comment: I would leave your answer until the OP clarifies their situation. As it stands right now, this is a correct answer to the problem presented in the question - even though the OP seems to have a different problem in reality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```js
$('#parent-nav li:last-child').css("border-top-right-radius","19px")
```

```css
li{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="tabs is-boxed">
    <ul id="parent-nav">
        <li class="is-active">
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/container/"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp; {{ Auth::user()->username }}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> &nbsp; Page1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> &nbsp; Page2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i> &nbsp; Page3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```